# drawing rect() on canvas with variables - works only with numbers?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Well, look at this code, mainly on `ctx.rect()` function in `drawPaddle` function and `var paddleY`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>GAME</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <style type="text/css">
  canvas {
   background-color: gray;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas width="500" height="500" id="myCanvas"></canvas>
 
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'); 
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var ballX = canvas.width / 2;
  var ballY = canvas.height - 80;
  var ballR = 10;
  var ballMX = 2;
  var ballMY = -2;
  var paddleX = (canvas.width / 2) - (130 / 2);
  var paddleY = canvas.height - paddleH;
  var paddleW = 130;
  var paddleH = 15;

  function drawPaddle() {
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.fillStyle = "green";
   ctx.rect(paddleX, paddleY, paddleW, paddleH);
   ctx.fill();
   ctx.closePath();
  }

  drawPaddle();
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

in `var paddleY` i got `canvas.height - paddleH`, this code do not draw paddle but when i change in `var paddleY` `canvas.height - 15` it is working why it's that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this part of your code:

```
var paddleY = canvas.height - paddleH;
var paddleW = 130;
var paddleH = 15;
```

You are defining paddleH only later. Which means, on the first line of this snippet, `paddleH` resolves to `undefined` and so the result is not a number, the rectangle can't be drawn. You need to initialize `paddleH` BEFORE calculating paddleY:

```
var paddleH = 15;
var paddleY = canvas.height - paddleH;
```

Now the script knows that `paddleH` is 15 and can draw the rectangle.